# purrr: unable to modify global list

Tags: r, purrr

Consider the following example:

```
test <- data_frame(link = c('https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Society'),
                                       counter = c(1,2))
> test
# A tibble: 2 x 2
                                                 link counter
                                                <chr>   <dbl>
1        https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page       1
2 https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Society       2
```

now I use `purrr:map2` to apply a simple function to both the `link` and the `counter` variable. The function is as follows:

```
data_list = list()

get_link <- function(link, counter){
  read_tmp <- read_html(link)
  data_list[[counter]] <- read_tmp 
}
```

The list remains empty. What I am trying to do is simply to store -at each iteration- `read_tmp` into a global list `data_list` that I want to access later on in the program.

However, calling: 
`purrr:map2(test$link, test$counter, ~get_link(.))`

**does not add anything**  to the `data_list` list.

What is the nasty scoping problem here? I thought I was modifying a global object that was defined outside the function...

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `purrr::map*` always returns a list (except the `purrr::map_*` variation), but the scoping is a bit changed in the implementation, as far as I am aware.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the code, but I've changed the `get_link` function to receive a data list and to return a modified (appended) version of if it and have the code working.

The following code:

```
library(rvest)

test <- data_frame(link = c('https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 
                            'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Society'),
                   counter = c(1,2))


get_link <- function(link, counter, data_list){
    read_tmp <- read_html(link)
    data_list[[counter]] <- read_tmp 
    data_list
}


data_list <- list()

purrr::map2(test$link, test$counter, ~get_link(.x, .y, data_list))
```

Returns the following list:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
{xml_document}
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<me ...
[2] <body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-0 ns-subject page-Ma ...


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
{xml_document}
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<me ...
[2] <body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-14 ns-subject page-C ...
```

Comment: thanks! do you have some sources to backup your claim that `but the scoping is a bit changed in the implementation, as far as I am aware.` ?